# Branching rule for $U(n) \hookrightarrow SO(2n)$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, branching-rules

I am going through Hamilton's book *Mathematical Gauge Theory*, in which he says

> If the representation $\rho$ of $G$ is irreducible, it may happen that the representation $\rho|_H$ of $H$ is reducible and decomposes as a direct sum. The actual form of the decomposition of a representation $\rho$ under restriction to a subgroup $H \subset G$ is called the branching rule.

I do not fully understand this definition and would like to see an example of a branching rule through the following exercise from his book. Let $V = \mathbb{C}^{2n}$ be the complex fundamental representation of $SO(2n)$, he asks the reader to determine the branching rule of the representation $V$ under restriction to the subgroup $U(n) \subset SO(2n)$.

Does finding the branching rule mean we determine how the representation decomposes into a direct sum when restricted to $U(n)$? If so, how would one do this?

Comment: When restricted to $U(n)$ you mean? Yes, exactly. In general the construction of branching rules can be quite complicated (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restricted_representation)) so if the book hasn't given you any more tools for this case then I suspect it wants you to work it out by hand. In this case, it's not too hard to see, as $n$ increases, there are only $3$ representations of $U(n)$ smaller than $\mathbb{C}^{2n}$ which are $\mathbb{C}^{n}$, $(\mathbb{C}^{n})^*$ and the trivial representation so it isn't too hard to guess the form of the decomposition and then prove it.

Comment: @Callum Yes that was a typo, thank you for catching that. How would one work out or notice that those are the only three representations smaller than $\mathbb{C}^{2n}$?

Comment: Just by familiarity with the representations of $U(n)$. The fundamental representations are the exterior powers $\bigwedge^k\mathbb{C}^n$ which have dimension $n$ choose $k$ (quickly exceeding $2n$ except for $k=1,n$). The other smallest representations are going to be the symmetric square $S^2\mathbb{C}$ and its dual which have dimension $n+1$ choose $2$ and the adjoint representation with dimension $n^2 -1$. Each of these have dimensions growing quadratically with $n$ so clearly exceed $2n$ eventually but actually this happens fairly early if you crunch the numbers.

Comment: Assuming there is a consistent pattern, we now only have a few choices, of which the most likely to me would seem to be $\mathbb{C}^n \oplus (\mathbb{C}^n)^*$ (as it is nicely symmetric). So now you can simply ask: does the subgroup $U(n) \subset SO(2n)$ fix two complementary subspaces of dimension $n$ and does it act on them the same or dual to each other

Comment: @Callum Thank you for your comment. I am familiar with exterior powers but I am fairly new to representation theory (including representations of specific groups such as $U(n)$, so it looks like I will have to do some more reading before attempting this problem.

Comment: Something like Fulton and Harris's Representation Theory might be a good shout for that. The second half is all about Lie groups. Note the representations of $\operatorname{U}(n)$ are the same as those of $\operatorname{SL}(n,\mathbb{C})$ and $\operatorname{sl}(n,\mathbb{C})$ and these are usually the first examples discussed